# When using whatsapp embedded signup I can't exchange code for access token

Tags: javascript, whatsapp-cloud-api

When implementing the WhatsApp embedded signup flow, I can redirect to the signup flow an retrieve an access code. When I want to exchange the access code for an access code, I get the following error message:

> OAuthException: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

My code:

```js
const fbAsyncInit = function () {
    // JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
    FB.init({
        appId:    '<APP_ID>', // Meta App ID
        cookie:   true, // enable cookies
        xfbml:    true, // parse social plugins on this page
        version:  'v18.0' //Graph API version
    });
};

fbAsyncInit();

function launchWhatsAppSignup() {
    // Launch Facebook login
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            const code = response.authResponse.code;
            //Use this token to call the debug_token API and get the shared WABA's ID
            resource.storeCredentials({token: code})
                .then((response) => {
                    router.push({name: 'integration.whatsapp.select-phone-number'})
                })
                .catch(setError);
        } else {
            console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {
        config_id: '<CONFIG_ID>', // configuration ID obtained in the previous step goes here
        response_type: 'code',     // must be set to 'code' for System User access token
        override_default_response_type: true,
        extras: {
            setup: {
                // Prefilled data can go here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I want to exchange the code for an access token using the following code:

```php
$response = Http::get('https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token', [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'code' => $this->code,
]);
```

I get the following error:

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

I used my localhost to test this out, I also did this on a live environment with a URL I specified in the Facebook login settings, but without any luck.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that that despite FB's docs being unclear about it, `redirect_uri` is a required parameter on your call to `https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/oauth/access_token`, and like the error says it must match the `redirect_uri` value on the previous call to start the `oauth/dialog` endpoint.

The problem with this that you and I both have is that we're using the FB JS SDK and the `FB.login(...)` method to authenticate/login. This process sets a `redirect_uri` (that we don't have access to and cannot override) within the popup.

I'm not sure there is a solution at this time. Facebook provides a broken JS SDK *and* its docs are misleading.

**UPDATE**

My org had to upgrade the whole FB Login App to [FB Login for Business](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/) within the Meta App Dashboard. At that point `redirect_uri` was no longer required.

Still don't know if there's any way around this without doing that upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

zigzags answer is correct, it has to do with the redirect_uri.. I was able to overcome this issue using the [manual-flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/?locale=es_LA). Basically you have to create the oauth url manually and open it, the following code worked for me:

```
function startEmbeddedSignupFlowManualUrl () {
  // Facebook's OAuth 2.0 endpoint for requesting an access token
  const oauth2Endpoint = 'https://www.facebook.com/v18.0/dialog/oauth'

  // Parameters to pass to the OAuth 2.0 endpoint.
  const params = {
    client_id: '<your_client_id>',
    redirect_uri: '<your_redirect_uri>',
    response_type: 'code',
    config_id: '<your_fb_login_config_id>',
    state: 'pass-through value'
  }

  // Construct the OAuth URL with parameters
  const oauthURL = `${oauth2Endpoint}?${new URLSearchParams(params).toString()}`

  // Open a new window for the OAuth flow
  window.location.replace(oauthURL)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Seems There is no changes are required in you code until you fix this error.
But there is definetly some configurations are remaining to do on your developer dashboard of facebook

Follow:

1.Go to Developer dashboard page / Go to Facebook Login for Business (Sidebar) / Settings

2.Make Sure OAuth Serrings are Enabled to YES

3.Add your live app url in below fields on the page

- Redirect URI Validator
- Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK
- Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

After this all, the feature will work on only https url (only in live app)

Answer (score 0):

You must use redirect_uri when call API get access token from code.

Please use redirect_uri as same as redirect_uri use with popup login facebook.

You can view setting redirect_uri in app facebook developer, choose the redirect_uri you are using

- Facebook login for business => Settings => Valid OAuth Redirect URIs

```html
var request = require('request');
var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://graph.facebook.com/<VER>/oauth/access_token?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&client_secret<CLIENT_SECRET>&code=<CODE>',
  'headers': {
    'Cookie': 'ps_l=0; ps_n=0'
  }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(response.body);
});
```

It's working for me